# select and unselect div on click on button in angularjs toggle action

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have multiple `div` containers in a page.

Each `div` has a button!

- On first click on that button:

  - The `div`'s `border-color` would change to blue (*Which means the `div` becomes `selected`*).
  - The "ok" button should hide (*Leaving only the selected `div` visible*).
- On second click anywhere inside the `div`; it should deselect it:

  - Border return to its black color.
  - Button becomes visible again.
- On click of select all button for first time, the div should select. After clicking next time for the same button it should get unselect. (Like toggle action)

How can I do this using AngularJS.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gLcjq3v/)

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.addBackground = function () {
       angular.element(document.querySelector('.container')).addClass('selectedBorder');
      angular.element(document.getElementById('okBtn')).css('display','none');
    };
};
```

```css
.container{
  width:30%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10%;
}
button.btn.btn-primary{
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
.selectedBorder{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="myAngularApp" title="Angular Scope" ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
<div class="container">
<button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addBackground()">ok</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited your code. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ns9q71rp/

Comment: You should not use DOM API inside jQuery unless it's inside directive.

Comment: @MaksymBezruchko Can you please update the code again. I have added one more point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-class` and `ng-show` in order to do it in **AngularJs** way:

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{ 'selectedBorder': containerSelected }" ng-click="toggleContainer()">
    <button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleButton($event)" ng-show="buttonVisible">ok</button> 
</div>

function MainCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.containerSelected = false;
   $scope.buttonVisible = true;
   $scope.toggleButton = function (e) {
       $scope.containerSelected = true;
       $scope.buttonVisible = false;
       e.stopPropagation();
    };
    $scope.toggleContainer = function (e) {
       if($scope.containerSelected){
           $scope.containerSelected = false;
           $scope.buttonVisible = true;
       }
    };

};
```

Working demo: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q1hf4j2e/21/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine. Can you please help me I have edited my fiddle. I have another button outside. If I click first time it should select. If I click the same button again it should unselect.

Comment: same action should come for outside selectall button also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation();` Using another event on click of box.

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.addBackground = function () {
       angular.element(document.querySelector('.container')).addClass('selectedBorder');
      angular.element(document.getElementById('okBtn')).css('display','none');
    };
    
    $scope.removeBackground = function () {
       angular.element(document.querySelector('.container')).removeClass('selectedBorder');
      angular.element(document.getElementById('okBtn')).css('display','initial');
    };
};
```

```css
.container{
  width:30%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10%;
}
button.btn.btn-primary{
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
.selectedBorder{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="myAngularApp" title="Angular Scope" ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="removeBackground()">
   
<div class="container">
<button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addBackground(); $event.stopPropagation();">ok</button> 
</div>
</div>
```